# find the path to the script which is running the query

Tags: mysql

is there any query to return information about the current script that is running it ? 
like for example if i have a file in

```
/home/domain/public_html/script.php
```

i want to put a query in it that file to return the  filename and path i.e :

```
/home/domain/public_html/script.php
```

or at least the base path to it ]

```
   /home/domain/public_html/
```

pleas note i know lots of method to do this but i specifically want to get these information back from database in response and after running a query

Comment: No, there is no such functionality built into mysql. How could it be, since you may connect to it remotely over the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way for the MySQL Server to know the name or path to the PHP script that is executing queries unless you tell it.

I've seen some projects that establish a coding practice to append a comment to the SQL queries with information to help you identify the source.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = 123; /* File: script.php, Function: myFunction() */
```

You then see these comments appearing in the MySQL processlist, and in query logs.

You have to write code to put the comment into the SQL yourself:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = 123; /* File: %s, Function: %s() */",
     __FILE__, __FUNCTION__);
```

If you don't want to change the code, another great solution is to use [New Relic Application Monitoring](https://newrelic.com/application-monitoring), which tracks SQL queries in code for you, without any need to modify your code. It's costly to pay for the New Relic service, but it's the best solution. If you want to explore cheaper alternatives, search google "alternatives to new relic".